# Pandas json_normalize fails with null values in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

i have below json which i get from external webservice :

```
text="""
     [{
        "id":"1",
         "name" : "abc",
         "address":{
                    "flat":"123",
                    "city":"paris",
                    "street":null
         },
         "error":null
     }]
```

Now i want to create dataframe from this json. When i try below :

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
import pandas as pd

resp_json = json.loads(text)
response = json_normalize(resp_json)
```

But this gives me below error:

`Error at response = json_normalize(resp_json)
 KeyError : 'street'`

I believe its because street attribute has value as null thats why it is throwing this error. How can this be resolved?

If i do like below, I am able to resolve but ideally its not the right solution

```
text = text.replace('"street":null','"street":""')
```

**NOTE:** -  When I use python verion 3.6.3 :: Anaconda Inc. and pandas version 0.20.3  I do not see this issue and json_normalize is able to work properly. This is my local machine setup.

On production machine we have - Python - 3.5.1 and pandas 0.23.0. There we encounter above issue.

Comment: Python 3.4 and pandas 0.20.1 - No problem, the code works properly as is.

Comment: yes with my local configuration as mentioned in question works aswell but its not working with configuration in production machine

Comment: @SCoder after looking at the documentation, it appears to be a bug in pandas 0.23.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the latest version of pandas:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21158

I'm running pandas '0.23.0' and I can reproduce the same error.
You can see in the github discussion thread that error arises due to condition case when *null* value occurs on the nesting level greater than 0. It seems to have been changed around two months ago that seems to have made it's way into 0.23.0 release two weeks ago:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/01882ba5b4c21b0caf2e6b9279fb01967aa5d650#diff-9c654764f5f21c8e9d58d9ebf14de86d

Other than waiting for the new release or downgrading your production env (which is not a good idea, since it will quite likely break things), you could think of how to handle multiple package versions in your env. Pip is not capable of doing so unless you create different virtual environments, neither is conda I believe. What you could do, if you really need to load files like those, is to load the '0.22.0' package as a local module by cloning it from git as a temporary, hacky, solution - just to load your dict. But there might be some dataframe API inconsistencies when you load with 0.22.0 and try to use it with 0.23.0.

Your solution of converting strings might not be that bad after-all.

Happy hacking.