# How to iterate json column to columns and then append origin dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':10,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3':'str1'}, 'c4':'41'}, {'c1':11,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3':'str2'},'c4':'42'}, {'c1':12,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3':'str3'},'c4':'43'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print (df)
```

The `df` is:

```
   c1  c4                      cols
0  10  41  {'c2': 20, 'c3': 'str1'}
1  11  42  {'c2': 20, 'c3': 'str2'}
2  12  43  {'c2': 20, 'c3': 'str3'}
```

The `cols` column is JSON type.

I need to make `cols` column to `json_decode`,which means change `df` to:

```
   c1    c4    c2      c3
0  10    41    20      str1
1  11    42    20      str2
2  12    43    20      str3
```

How to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(inp)
```

Outputs

```
    c1  c4  cols.c2 cols.c3
0   10  41  20      str1
1   11  42  20      str2
2   12  43  20      str3
```

---

If you have a `pd.DataFrame`, convert back using `to_dict`

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.to_dict('records'))
```

Comment: Actually, I found it's a bug.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645240/pandas-json-normalize-fails-with-null-values-in-json

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column, convert to numpy array and lists and pass to DataFrame constructor, last [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('cols').values.tolist(), index=df.index))
print (df)
   c1  c4  c2    c3
0  10  41  20  str1
1  11  42  20  str2
2  12  43  20  str3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df['cols'].tolist()))
df.drop('cols', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   c1  c4  c2    c3
0  10  41  20  str1
1  11  42  20  str2
2  12  43  20  str3
```