# `NameError: name 'NaT' is not defined` and `NameError: name 'Timestamp' is not defined`

Tags: python, pandas

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281085/how-to-iterate-json-column-to-columns-and-then-append-origin-dataframe/55281298#55281298),

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':10,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3':'str1'}, 'c4':'41'}, {'c1':11,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3':'str2'},'c4':'42'}, {'c1':12,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3':'str3'},'c4':'43'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.to_dict('records'))
```

Above script works well.

Make little change to `inp`:

```
inp=[{'c1':10,'cols':{'c2':5,'c3':NaT}, 'c4':'41'}, {'c1':11,'cols':{'c2':Timestamp('2014-06-03 21:19:26'),'c3':'str2'},'c4':'42'}, {'c1':12,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3':'str3'},'c4':'43'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.to_dict('records'))
```

I just change `str1` to `NaT` and `20` to `Timestamp('2014-06-03 21:19:26')`,script works not well, got error as below:

```
NameError: name 'NaT' is not defined
NameError: name 'Timestamp' is not defined
```

As `NaT` is common in real data,what's the problem cause error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be referring to pd.NaT and [pd.Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

```
inp=[{'c1':10,'cols':{'c2':5,'c3':pd.NaT}, 'c4':'41'}, {'c1':11,'cols':{'c2':pd.Timestamp('2014-06-03 21:19:26'),'c3':'str2'},'c4':'42'}, {'c1':12,'cols':{'c2':20,'c3':'str3'},'c4':'43'}]
```

Comment: `df` come from `df = pd.read_sql(...`, I checked `df`, there's only `NaT`,no any `pd.NaT`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. NaT is a type available directly from pandas not the dataframe object: `(N)ot-(A)-(T)ime, the time equivalent of NaN`

Comment: when you get dataframe through `df=pd.read_sql(...`,if there's any missing date value, should be `NaT`.Do I need to replace those `NaT` to `pd.NaT`?

Comment: You need to tell `df.read_sql` what columns you want to parse to a date with the `parse_dates` parameter. For example: `df = sql.read_sql(query, con=conn, parse_dates=['col_id1', 'col_id2'])`

Comment: `NaT` is the representation of the object. It is just how the object is *displayed*. If you `print(pd.NaT)`, what is displayed is `NaT`. You are probably copying and pasting the output of a print directly into code. Obviously, this is incorrect and won't work.